# how to easily erase(delete all partitions and start again) and format drives on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

On using Disk Utility on OS X, I can easily erase and  format drives/USB sticks. I can even select the partitioning scheme? (GPT, MBR and 1 other option)

I want to erase all partitions and format disk in 1 step in Windows 10. With the option of selecting GPT or MBR when formatting.

I do not find a similar utility that's built-in on Windows. I've certainly looked at Computer Management/Disk Management and it's definitely nothing like OS X Disk Utility.

Any ideas on achieve what I want? Thanks

Comment: If you show us what you are seeing we might be able to say why you are not able to erase all the partitions.

Comment: If you are doing this on a hundred drives I could see a use for a one click solution. But, I fail to see why a few clicks in disk management is a problem for the rare instance you would need do this? If you were to be doing this to a hundred drives, then windows provides other automated tools depending on the scenario, which you haven't provided in your question.

Comment: @Appleoddity when I left/right-click on my USB stick, I see no way of converting it to MBR/GPT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line tool

diskpart

- select disk 1
- clean

Drive is now empty.

- convert gpt
- create partition primary size=300
- format quick fs=ntfs label="Windows"
- assign letter="c"

Comment: while not a 1-step process, seems this is the closest thing for Windows. Thank you

Comment: After starting `diskpart` run `list disk` to make sure the correct disk is selected